# drupal_goto(request_uri()) replaces my '?', '=' and '&' in url

Tags: 7, uri, views

I need to redirect user from a page with example.com/node/add/dispo?arg1=1&arg2=2 to the same type of URL. But when I simply do a `drupal_goto(request_uri());`, it redirects my user to example.com/node/add/dispo%25F%3C etc....

I tried a str_replace but it didnt work.

Would you have any workaround ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) accepts an `$options` parameter to be passed on to the [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) function. You can pass a query string like this:

```
$options = array('query' => array('foo' => 'bar'));
drupal_goto('path', $options);
```

That example will forward on to /path?foo=bar

Comment: I guess it's cleaner than header(location ?

Comment: It depends really, if you look at the code all `drupal_goto()` does is build up a URL based on provided parameters which it then calls `header()` on itself. The main differences are that `drupal_exit()` is called, giving a clean exit to the script, and if `$_GET['destination']` is set, that will override the path that you pass to the function. Generally `drupal_goto()` should be used, but there are occasions when good old `header()` is more appropriate. Just depends what you need to do

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll use header for this one but still, I guess drupal_goto is cleaner.

Comment: notice that the options array has an array query with name and value pair. So my code to log in with a destination variable looks like this:
$options = array('query'=>array('destination'=>'internal/dashboard')    
drupal_goto('user', $options));

Comment: Amazing got to learn something new

Answer (score 13):

This is same as Clive's answer. It's correct IMO but I just wanted to add the answer that suits your use case 1:1.

```
$options = array('query' => drupal_get_query_parameters());
drupal_goto(current_path(), $options);
```

You wanted to call `drupal_goto()` to the same location as the current one.

```
mysite.com/node/add/dispo?arg1=1&arg2=2
```

[current_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7) returns node/add/dispo; [drupal_get_query_parameters()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7) returns all `$_GET` parameters except `$_GET['q']` which is the internal path node/add/dispo.

When you call `drupal_goto()`, Drupal can rebuild the same URI to send the user to.

Comment: Great, I upped your answer as I keep Clive's chosen. Thx you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `drupal_goto($GLOBALS['base_root'] . request_uri());`

Note that it is not same as `drupal_goto(request_uri());` where the passed parameter is urlencoded as if it is an internal drupal path, which is actually the source of your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I made it work by using `header("location: " . $base_path . request_uri());`

Comment: this is wrong. drupal_goto is made for some reason you know.